# Is it possible to send Firebase push notification to specific token and also to the topic

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications by specifying `device-token` and also a specific `Topic`.
Is it possible to do this using `Firebase admin-SDK`? [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics-legacy) specifies `Topics` and `device-token` methods separately but no clear definition to use both methods together.

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
admin.messaging().sendToTopic("TOPIC", payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API (neither in the Admin SDK, nor in the REST API that is uses under the hood) to send messages to both topics and a set of tokens with a single call.

The closest I can think of is to have those devices subscribe to a secondary token, and then [using an `OR` condition to send to both topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics).